# Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server

Tags: php, ldap, xampp

Environment:

LDAP Server Type: ActiveDirectory

LdapRecord-Laravel Major Version: v2.5

PHP Version: 8.0

I'm using `ldaprecord` and I'm getting

```
"ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server. Error Code: [-1"
```

when I run php artisan ldap:test , can you help me how I can fix this bug knowing that I'm using xammp , thanks a lot

```
Connection | Successful | Username | Message | Response Time |
+------------+------------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
| default | ✘ No | | ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server. Error Code: [-1] Diagnostic Message: null | 10082.94ms |
```

Comment: You'd need to share some configuration and tell us more about your environment.

Comment: im using connection with the env , and im working on windows with xampp  this is my env.file                                                                                      
        LDAP_LOGGING=true

LDAP_CONNECTION=default
LDAP_CONNECTIONS=default                                              
LDAP_DEFAULT_HOSTS=ldap.forumsys.com  
LDAP_DEFAULT_USERNAME=null
LDAP_DEFAULT_PASSWOR=null       
LDAP_DEFAULT_PORT=389
LDAP_DEFAULT_BASE_DN="cn=read-only-admin"
LDAP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=5
LDAP_DEFAULT_SSL=false
LDAP_DEFAULT_TLS=false

Comment: thnaks manu i got this and i dont know how i suppose interpret this  ComputerName     : ldap.forumsys.com
RemoteAddress    : 64:ff9b::6b17:a2de
RemotePort       : 389
InterfaceAlias   : Wi-Fi
SourceAddress    : 2a04:cec0:c016:8d68:5867:9f9e:a97b:9c7b
TcpTestSucceeded : True

Comment: this means, that regarding the network connection there is everything fine.
Do you have an actual Active Directory to test it on rather than this public test LDAP service?

Comment: I am also having the same issue when upgraded to XAMPP 8.2.4. When I was using 8.0.0.0 I was using security 636 port. I am using the same on  my current new server but it is giving me the same error your getting @ZOHBOU

Comment: @ZOHBOU Did you find an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

See this [example](https://ldaprecord.com/docs/laravel/v2/configuration/#using-an-environment-file-env)

You'll need to set a proper user and password for `LDAP_DEFAULT_USERNAME` and `LDAP_DEFAULT_PASSWORD`.

Your `LDAP_DEFAULT_BASE_DN` is not supposed to be a user, rather the OU you want to enter with LDAP which contians everything you want to query.

Example for the whole domain: `"dc=local,dc=com"`

Also make sure your domain controller is reachable on `TCP 389` from your system.

Comment: thanks for your answer but still it dont work i think the porblem is in the ssl/tls and im using xampp i dont know how to ad a ldap.conf in my server directory

Comment: By default LDAP on Port 389 is not encrypted and does not require ssl/tls.
Check first for connectivity to this port. Example in Powershell: Test-Netconnection -Computername ldap.forumsys.com -Port 389

Answer (score 0):

I was getting an error like this on Red Hat Server due to selinux.

Running this on the server fixed the issue:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_connect_ldap on
```